# R: Changing column types with dplyr based on vector of column names producing error

Tags: r, dplyr, types

I'm trying to change the type of a subset of columns in a data frame using `dplyr` syntax, where the subset of columns is identified by a character vector containing the names of the columns I would like to operate on. Since I'm working on multiple columns at once, I'm using `across()`. Since I'm passing an external vector of names, I'm using `all_of()`. However, I obtain the below error when actually doing this.

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
> x Input `..2` must be a vector, not a primitive function.
> i Input `..2` is `as.character`.

An example that reproduces the error is found below.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create example data
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                 y = rnorm(10))

cols_to_convert <- c("x","y")

df %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols_to_convert)),
              as.character)
```

Comment: You closed the bracket `)` too early.  Shoul dbe `df %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols_to_convert),
              as.character))`

Comment: Ah, yes. I always found this counterintuitive since I expected something like mutate(.data,.cols,function). Thank you.

Comment: I've always assumed a loose consensus of: `)` is a paren, `]` is a bracket, and `}` is a brace. It's good to recalibrate my assumptions :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this was a simple issue of using a bracket too early.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create example data
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                 y = rnorm(10))

cols_to_convert <- c("x","y")

df %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols_to_convert),
              as.character))
```